# Using querySelector exclude elements whose id's include a specific string

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-selectors

I want to get results whose id does not include a string (let's say it's is "test")

```
<ul class="numberlist">
  <li id="test1" style="display:none">
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>one</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>two</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>three</a>
  </li>
  <li id="test2" style="display:none">
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>four</a>
  </li> 
  <li id="test" style="display:none">
    </div></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

As I said I want to exclude which has id that includes string `test`. How can I achieve it?

I can get the list of `<li>`'s by writing

```
document.querySelectorAll('ul.numberList')
```

But I want to exclude some of them by their id's.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use **[attribute contains selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)** with **[`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not)** pseudo-class selector

```
document.querySelectorAll('ul.numberlist li:not([id*="test"])')
```

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('ul.numberlist li:not([id*="test"])').length)
```

```html
<ul class="numberlist">
  <li id="test1" style="display:none">
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>one</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>two</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>three</a>
  </li>
  <li id="test2" style="display:none">
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>four</a>
  </li>
  <li id="test" style="display:none">
    <div></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

**FYI :** `document.querySelectorAll('ul.numberList')` , doesn't get all `li` element, instead which gets all `ul` with class `numberList`. To get all `li` inside use selector as `ul.numberList li`. Also in your html class name is `numberlist` not `numberList`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for `:not()` and "starts with" selectors:

```
document.querySelectorAll('ul.numberList li:not([id^=test])')
```

(Or replace `^` with `*` in case you want "includes", not "starts with")

Comment: he didn't say the 'if id starts with', but 'if id includes', so I think starts with is not correct modifier to use here.

Comment: @Mike See last line in my answer.

Comment: yeah, saw that after I submitted my comment. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me figure out the following - I want to query based on an id string but exclude from those another id string: `document.querySelectorAll('[id^="primary_container"]:not([id="primary_container-__prefix__"])')`